# Can't run program with quoted argument from script, but can run it directly from the command-line

Tags: powershell, youtube-dl

I have this script (which is aliased to `ydl` in my profile):

```
param(
    [string]$url,
    [switch]$vid=$false
)

$ydl = "D:\youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe"

$mp3conf = "--config-location `"D:/youtube-dl/config-mp3.txt`""
$vidconf = "--config-location `"D:/youtube-dl/config-mp4.txt`""

$finalArgs = $mp3conf

If ($vid) {
    $finalArgs = $vidconf
}

Write-Host $ydl $url $finalArgs
& $ydl $url $finalArgs
```

Powershell output:

```
PS D:\> ydl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_7Mcb6iLN0
D:\youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123 --config-location "D:/youtube-dl/config-mp3.txt"
Usage: youtube-dl.exe [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl.exe: error: no such option: --config-location D:/youtube-dl/config-mp3.txt
```

Ok? That is unfortunate... but what if I try to directly run the command -- copying it from the `Write-Host` output from the script?

Powershell says the list of arguments results in this:
`D:\youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123 --config-location "D:/youtube-dl/config-mp3.txt"`

Ok, let's try:

```
PS D:\> D:\youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123 --config-location "D:/youtube-dl/config-mp3.txt"
[youtube] 123: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 123: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 123: Extracting video information
[youtube] 123: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Destination: D:\youtube-dl\MP3\123.webm
[download] 100% of 2.48MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Destination: D:\youtube-dl\MP3\123.mp3
Deleting original file D:\youtube-dl\MP3\123.webm (pass -k to keep)
```

What gives? How does it work in the command line but not in the script?

Comment: You may need to escape the backslash with another backslash?

Comment: `& $ydl $url '--%' $finalArgs`. *Powershell says the list of arguments results in this:* No, it is what `Write-Host` print to you. PowerShell have different logic when passing arguments to native applications.

Comment: @PetSerAl, that sure did it. Thanks! Submit as answer if you want the points.